# I am not sure how to address this execution halted error in knitting rmarkdown file to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I've been trying to knit this rmarkdown file, however this "execution halted" message appears. I'm new to rstudio/rmarkdown, and I'm not entirely sure what this means, nor how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

```
sh: /private/var/folders/zt/c0g089md6ll66l3ndq2rmy680000gn/T/AppTranslocation/BE1FDC09-D505-4BAD-B121-86557E3F6D2D/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable
Error in strsplit(info, "\n")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... pandoc_available -> find_pandoc -> lapply -> FUN -> get_pandoc_version
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command ''/private/var/folders/zt/c0g089md6ll66l3ndq2rmy680000gn/T/AppTranslocation/BE1FDC09-D505-4BAD-B121-86557E3F6D2D/d/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc' --version' had status 126
Execution halted
```

[image]

I tried reinstalling r and rstudio, but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? It is difficult to help you without a reproducible example.

Comment: Does your RMD have a line of code looking like `strsplit(info, "\n")`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.